# How to know Which Regions are Near Some Location in Google Map

Tags: xcode, annotations, mkmapview

Say I am in a location.

Near that location there are regions and famous buildings

like region, kepaduri, wisconsin street, etc.

Is there a way to query google and get info what are the close things near me?

Basically I am making an IPhone apps and I want to populate the autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a webservice where you send coordinates and it returns a list of "regions" that are nearby I don't beleive Google provides that, and if they did, it's got nothing to do with MKMapView.

Comment: how the hell google map does so though? I am sure google has that. Yes that's what I mean by the way.